# Cordova Build Failed - :transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug

Tags: android, cordova

I am a front-end developer and I am working on CSS for an app for a tech company. Because I do primarily front-end I'm somewhat unfamiliar on what to do when cordova fails to build, though I usually get through it by searching, I cannot find a solution to this problem. Any help is appreciated!

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   >     android/support/v4/graphics/BitmapCompat.class

Answer (score 0):

How do you build your cordova app.Is it CLI way or through Android studio.
Try building CLI way.It looks some Android library, building twice.Delete your gradle from your path .Build your app again .

It looks old gradle is still in your gradle path.